# What is the fewest number of satellites required to have constant global coverage?

Tags: orbit-selection

How can I guarantee global coverage with the fewest number of satellites? Assume that link margin isn't a problem.

Comment: This depends on the heights of the orbits of the satellites. The higher the orbit, the larger the area a satellite can cover and the less satellites you need.

Comment: @Philipp: I'm assuming the height doesn't matter at all (Link margin isn't a problem). A 100km orbit, or a 100000 orbit doesn't matter for this purpose.

Comment: The height does matter. With infinite height, you would only need two satellites, because each one has direct line to each point of a whole hemisphere. With zero height, you would need an infinite number of satellites, because each satellite has direct line-of-sight to only a single point. With a height in between, you need... a number in between. That's the purpose of satellites in the first place.

Comment: As someone who has no experience with satellite calculations (so this may sound dumb), if link margin isn't an issue what's stopping you from having two satellites in GEO on opposite sides of the earth? I'm guessing there's some assumed context I'm missing that would be more apparent to an expert.

Comment: @called2voyage: There's a small spot that you don't have coverage if you just have two satellites, along the ring. GEO orbit covers about 45% of the Earth's surface area, two GEO would cover 90%. You never can get fully 100% though just GEO satellites.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto Then couldn't you get it with four?

Comment: @called2voyage: Still miss the poles, no matter how many GEO satellites you have.

Comment: Four GSO that is, two in GEO and two in polar GSO?

Comment: You'd still miss a small spot by doing that. I think 2 GEO and 4 GSO polar would work, but I'm curious if there's a smaller number out there.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto Strictly in theory, a triangular pyramid can bound a sphere, so four satellites should be able to maintain global coverage given some very unusual orbits.

Comment: Bibliography: Lueders (1961) Walker (1970) Mozhaev (1972) Ballard (1980) Rider (1985) Draim (1985) Lang (1998) ... See also Streets of Coverage and the Walker method. :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others mentioned in the comments, a 4-satellite constellation is the minimum that will give you global coverage. [Here](http://www.google.com/patents/US4809935) is Draim's patent (it also includes a 3-satellite constellation for hemispherical coverage), and a coverage map from [here](http://personal.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Personal/L.Wood/software/SaVi/Draim/) is shown below.

Regarding GEO satellites, while a 3-satellite constellation in GEO *will* give you full coverage for all *longitudes*, the same is not true for all *latitudes*. Coverage as you approach the poles gets spotty, particularly when you include considerations like minimum elevation angle.

[image: Coverage map for Draim tetrahedral constellation]